# Refreshing the listview in a certain time Android

Tags: android, listview

I am developing an android app with bluetooth communication.Server is sending some data to   client the client is storing the data in sqlite and display it in a listView and whenever the ListView activity starts The UI should update in each 20 seconds. How can I update/refresh my UI ?

Comment: if you want to update your listview only, listviewAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use timer ... to refresh it after every 20s.

```
CountDownTimer countDownTime = new CountDownTimer(20000,1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      yourlistadpter.notifyDatasetChanged();
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You should refresh your adapter object by calling `notifyDatasetChanged()` method periodically.

Comment: Can I have an example.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Timer, TimerTask and handler to update your UI periodically..once you get new data you can update your listview by calling

```
yourlistadpter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```